# Is it a granted patent?

Tags: granted

In reference to the patent: [CA2861405A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2861405A1)

Is this a granted patent?
Has Econovate ltd. any granted patent?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Google Patents page for that patent, you will see a "PCT number" (Patent Cooperation Treaty). That means it was filed as an international patent (the original document is the one with a publication number like 'WOxxxxxxxxxA1', in this case [WO 2013/117929 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013117929A1), and the information on national status will be on the WIPO site ([Patentscope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2013117929)). Click on the 'National phase' tab to find the status of the patent in all countries:

```
Office                  Entry Date  National Number  National Status
Canada                  15.07.2014  2861405  
European Patent Office  11.07.2014  2013705238       Published: 17.12.2014
```

You can also view the status of the Canadian publication on the "Admin status" page at [CIPO](http://brevets-patents.ic.gc.ca/opic-cipo/cpd/eng/patent/2861405/summary.html).